# Hebrew 1:10 means according to the Catholic?

Tags: hebrews

I read from this [link](https://carm.org/jesus-chist/jesus-given-authority-name) where some of the sentence is talking about God is always the same. Below is the verse quoted from that link :

> You, Lord, in the beginning laid the foundation of the earth, And the
>   heavens are the works of Your hands; They will perish, but You remain;
>   And they all will **become old** like a garment, And like a mantle You
>   will roll them up; Like a garment they will also be changed. But You
>   are the same, And Your years will not come to an end

So I think from the point-of-view of the writer of the verse above is that *if something become old then it's **not the same** anymore*. In other words, in the writer's point of view is that *God will not become old*, hence he wrote : *"But You are the same"*.

Assuming the writer is there also with the baby, Mary and Josef at the stable, and Mary say to the writer *"this is The Lord you wrote about"*. Then after three years past, the writer see that the baby becomes old, will the writer's following argument valid ?

The Lord will not become old 
This one become old 
So, this one is not The Lord.

Comment: from which denomination do you want an interpretation from, as various denominations have differing perspectives

Comment: hi depperm, thank you for your suggestion. I reworded the title of my question. Now the question is for the Catholic.

Comment: Do you really give 6¢ what Roman Catholicism has to say about this or is this a band-aide trying to get the question re-opened? If what you really want is an analysis and interpretation of the text I suggest reverting the edit and flag for migration to [hermeneutics.se] instead.

Comment: @caleb, when I put questions in SE, most of the time is for the Calvinist. When depperm ask me which denomination I want an interpretation from, I remember one of my Catholic friend say that the baby know that actually he doesn't need anything, milk, food, etc. So then I choose the answer from the Catholic because I assume the "origin" teaching that the baby is God is from the Catholic.

Answer (score 1):

Your question touches on a question that perplexed the Church.

See https://www.ligonier.org/blog/does-jesus-have-two-natures-or-one/

A brief quote:

> In the year 451, the church convened the great Council of Chalcedon,
>   one of the most important ecumenical councils of all time. It was
>   called to combat several heresies, the most significant of which was
>   the Monophysite heresy. The term monophysite has a prefix and a root.
>   The prefix, mono, means “one,” and the root, phusis, is translated as
>   “nature.” So monophusis or monophysite simply means “one nature.”

All churches that accept the finding of the Council of Chalcedon, including most protestant denominations, the Roman Catholic Church and the Eastern Orthodox Church, therefore believe that Jesus has two natures in one person: divine and human.

With this understanding, the answer to your question is that the divine nature of Jesus did not age, because it is ageless. However, the human nature of Jesus did begin at birth, then age, then die on the cross, then rise from the dead. The contradiction is resolved if you accept that there is a vastness to God that earlier ideas of His existence and nature could not grapple with.

However, there is a danger in viewing this relationship between the human nature and the divine nature of Christ in a materialistic way. This touches on another question, regarding the question of whether God is simple or complex. God is simple, and cannot be broken into smaller pieces, like bodies broken into cells, cells into molecules, molecules into atoms, atoms into protons and electrons, and protons into quarks, gluons, mesons and strings.

See https://www.placefortruth.org/blog/classic-theism-god-simple-or-complex for an exploration of this question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and your links (I've read the first one), Paul Chernoch. But I admit that I still unable to grasp it. I wonder "what if the baby is a girl ?". What is to say ? Will it be _"she has two natures in one **person**: divine and human"_ ? What is "a person" ? Is a person grow old ?

Comment: The concept of what a person is in Catholic dogma, such that a single God can consist of three persons, is a whole other question, and probably covered in other questions on this site.